# How to disable bottom "show-on-drag" menu in Gnome?

Tags: linux, debian, gnome

I'm not quite sure what the menu is called, but when I drag my mouse against the bottom of the screen in Gnome (1:3.14+3), a new menu appears. I do this by accident a lot and find it very annoying.

The Gnome package is Debian version 1:3.14+3, and according to `/usr/share/gnome/gnome-version.xml` the version is 3.14.1.

Is there some way to disable this behavior?
[image: grey menu at the bottom is the problem menu]

Answer (score 0):

That's the notification area. You cannot disable it.

You could, however, upgrade to GNOME 3.20 in Debian 'testing' (unfortunately it's not backported to jessie). The notification area has been moved to a different design *a few releases ago.*